# Traceback - can't get the exception text?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use a try/except block:

```
try:
    raise ValueError
except Exception as e:
       # Get error data
       stack = traceback.extract_stack()
       (filename, line, procname, text) = stack[-1]
       # create sendable error data
       error_data = {
           "error_msg": f"Line No. {line}\nText: \n\n{text}",
           "error_script": filename,
            }
       # send email to admin
       resp = req.post(f"{ERRORS_URL}", headers=header, json=error_data)
       pass
```

When I get an email from here:

I receive the `filename`, `line` without any issue. The `text` however is always blank.

I want the text to be the cause of the exception.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: if you want `text` to be the cause of exception, why not use `e` instead - you already are pulling it out from the exception

Comment: @oskros thats a good point I will try to use `e` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `sys.exc_info()` to get information about the exception, and not traceback - if you use traceback, you will get the line no from where you call `stack = traceback.extract_stack()` rather than the line no where the error occurred.

Furthermore, you are not getting anything in the error text if you just raise a `ValueError` without a message - there needs to be a cause for the error in order to have an error message.

Below is an example where line number, filename and exception message is extracted and inserted into your dictionary for a simple zero devision error:

```py
import sys
import os


def foo():
    try:
        1 / 0
    except Exception as e:
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        line = exc_tb.tb_lineno
        filename = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]

        error_data = {
            "error_msg": f"Line No. {line}\nText: \n\n{e}",
            "error_script": filename,
        }
        return error_data


print(foo())
>>> {'error_msg': 'Line No. 7\nText: \n\ndivision by zero', 'error_script': 'test_file.py'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `e.__class__.__name__` instead of `text` to get the reason.

```
>>> {'error_msg': 'Line No. 6\nText: \n\n', 'error_script': 'Error.py'}
```

I hope this helps.